# Print not working in ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2010

Hi i am using Report service client definition (`rdlc`) for reporting in my `asp.net` web application.
I used a `reportviwer`  for displaying report. But while clicking on the print button of report viwer the `following error` occures
[image]

[image]
Here is my aspx portion

```
<div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Visible ="false" Width="100%" Height="100%" ShowPrintButton="true">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
```

If anybody knows please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print button of SSRS report viewer is an ActiveX control.

This works only on IE. If you are using any other browser you will not be able to load this control. This ActiveX control is known to cause problems with IE 9 too.

So unless you stuck to a really old environment of IE7,IE8. Don't bother to use the print control that comes with reportviewer.

Provide a button to export the same report as PDF, and let your users print from there.

Answer (score 0):

Where we've seen this problem, it's been because users haven't had permissions to install the ActiveX control into IE.

There's two suggested solutions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2010/04/13/error-unable-to-load-client-print-control-when-printing-reports-in-reporting-services-summary-of-all-possible-causes-at-april-2010.aspx), one of which is to deploy the ActiveX control manually onto each machine where it's needed.